# Android : Block mirroring, HDMI, GoogleCast for an activity

Tags: android, chromecast, mirroring, hdmi

Does anybody know if there is a way to prevent an activity to be cast on another screen than the screen of the device?

I would like to prevent the user to be able to stream the content of the activity with **HDMI**, **Google Cast**, **adb shell screenrecord** or any other mirroring tools I might miss.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The reason is because if your app does not re-enable those features, the user has no way to re-enable them. There is no item in Settings to toggle these things on or off.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I understand that I can't change the settings but this is not what I'm trying to do.
I'm trying to secure only an activity programmatically, the same way the flag WindowManager.FLAG_SECURE works to prevent thean activity to be 'screenhotted'.